# Turn off Ruby 2.1 Deprecated RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS Warning

Tags: ruby

I have some GC settings in my `.bash_profile`:

```
export RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS=1250000
export RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_INCREMENT=100000
export RUBY_HEAP_SLOTS_GROWTH_FACTOR=1
export RUBY_GC_MALLOC_LIMIT=30000000
export RUBY_HEAP_FREE_MIN=12500
```

When I use Ruby 2.1, it's complaining about `RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS`:

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby: warning: RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS is obsolete. Use RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS instead.
```

I migrate to `RUBY_GC_HEAP_INIT_SLOTS`, but this warning still shows up. Does anyone know how to turn this off? Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Did you reload your `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Yes. Source & Reload!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
unset RUBY_HEAP_MIN_SLOTS
```

to delete the environmental variable.

Comment: Is this really "the" solution? Not just a workaround? Somewhere this var is being set, isn't it?